# Prove you can't make a natural spline from a B-spline, from a polynomial of third degree.

Tags: numerical-methods, spline

How can I prove the following:

Given a polynomial $f(x)$ of third degree, suppose you have another polynomial $S(x)$ which is a B-spline representation of $f(x)$. Prove that it is not possible to make a natural spline polynomial of $S(x)$.

My approach was that since $S(x)$ is not a smooth function because it is in segments, a natural spline representation would not be possible. Also, if you take the same points you used for the B-spline, then it is not even differentiable.

How can I make it a much more formal proof and is my approach correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me what you mean with "....make a natural spline polynomial of $S(x)$", so I will assume you meant "$S(x)$ is not a natural cubic spline".

To prove this is pretty simple. Assuming $S(x)$ exactly represents the $[x_0, x_1]$ portion of $f(x)$, if $S(x)$ is a natural cubic spline then its 2nd derivatives should be zero at $x_0$ and $x_1$ (this is by definition). Consequently, we must have $f''(x_0)=f''(x_1)=0$.  This condition is not necessarily true and therefore $S(x)$ is not necessarily a natural cubic spline.

Comment: Just saying its not necessarly true is not a proof of the statement. Note that $f$ being cubic means $f''(x)$ is linear.